# Adding aws-java-sdk breaks spring boot tomcat loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aws-sdk

I am trying to add aws-sdk-1.11.913 to my spring boot 2.0.6, pom.xml-

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.913</version>
</dependency>
```

Console output -

```
2020-12-07 17:14:33.936  INFO 3016 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2020-12-07 17:14:34.890  INFO 3016 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-12-07 17:14:34.890  INFO 3016 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
2020-12-07 17:14:34.893  INFO 3016 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\JAVA_@\jdk1.8.0_151\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/JAVA_@/clean/jdk-11.0.6+10/bin/client;C:/Program Files/JAVA_@/clean/jdk-11.0.6+10/bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\helm\windows-amd64;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\bin;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\apache-ant-1.10.5-bin\apache-ant-1.10.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Minikube;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Program Files\Kubernetes\Minikube;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Redis\;C:\Gradle\gradle-6.7.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X86\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X86\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JAVA_@\clean\jdk-11.0.6+10\bin;C:\Windows\System32\sapjco3.dll;C:\Users\oqwvm5\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.siemens.plm.it\sapjco3\3.1.2\c83fa6472f0c45339bcb1d4fc6e9a2687e2046fc\sapjco3.jar;C:\sapsnc;;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\helm\windows-amd64;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\bin;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\apache-ant-1.10.5-bin\apache-ant-1.10.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Minikube;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.2.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Program Files\Kubernetes\Minikube;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Redis\;C:\Gradle\gradle-6.7.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X86\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pulse Secure\VC142.CRT\X86\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JAVA_@\clean\jdk-11.0.6+10\bin;C:\Windows\System32\sapjco3.dll;C:\Users\oqwvm5\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.siemens.plm.it\sapjco3\3.1.2\c83fa6472f0c45339bcb1d4fc6e9a2687e2046fc\sapjco3.jar;C:\sapsnc;;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\helm\windows-amd64;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\S;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;%IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition%;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Salesforce CLI\bin;C:\Users\oqwvm5\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;;C:\WINDOWS\system32;;.]
2020-12-07 17:14:35.210  INFO 3016 --- [ost-startStop-1] .[.[/storeservices/api/ordersmanagement] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-12-07 17:14:38.170  INFO 3016 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] .[.[/storeservices/api/ordersmanagement] : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

And the loading "freezes", removing this dependency and the project loads successfully.
Spring version-

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Java -

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Should I use different sdk version?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by adding only the dependency I need-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.913</version>
</dependency>
```